# Using React, NodeJS, and Postgres: Having trouble being able to delete and updating todos

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express

I am creating simple todo app with postgre and react.

The server side the delete and update are defined as below.

```
app.put("/todos/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const { description } = req.body;
    const updateTodo = await pool.query(
      "update todo set description = $1 where todo_id = $2",
      [description, id]
    );
    res.json("todo updated !!");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
  }
});

// delete todo
app.delete("/todos/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const deleteTodo = await pool.query("delete from todo where todo_id = $1", [
      id,
    ]);
    res.json("todo deleted !!");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
  }
});
```

On the front end (React) this is how I am calling the update and delete

```
  const updateDescription = async () => {
    try {
      handleClose();
      const body = { description };
      const response = fetch(`http://localhost:3000/${todo.todo_id}`, {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
      });
      console.log(response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };
```

Delete todo is in the other component.

```
  const deleteTodo = async (id) => {
    try {
      const deleteTodo = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/${id}`, {
        method: "DELETE ",
      });
      console.log(deleteTodo);
      setTodods(todos.filter((todo) => todo.todo_id !== id));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };
```

So when I am doing delete or put request its not updating it in the DB.

On the browser console I am getting this error.

```
Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': 'DELETE ' is not a valid HTTP method.
```

**Edited**

```
Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:3000/3", redirected: false, status: 404, ok: false, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 404
statusText: "Not Found"
type: "cors"
url: "http://localhost:3000/3"
__proto__: Response
```

For insert todo its working but for delete and put request its not updating in the database.

So can somebody tell me whats going wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a space after `DELETE`, correct it should work properly. Even if its a simple todo App, its always good practice to create an `enum` or `const` when we are dealing with fixed string, i.e., we know the string would not change so that we can have consistency and skip over these kind of issues.

```
const METHOD = {
 GET: "GET",
 PUT: "PUT",
 POST: "POST",
 DELETE: "DELETE" 
};
```

Comment: That helped. But ts only updating on the front end side. But database is not updated. I am getting other error on the browser console. You can see in edit section.

Comment: I think you are trying to perform some action on the resource that doesn't exist. When are you seeing the new error, is it on PUT or DELETE ?

Comment: On delete. The resource is exists if I do it on postman its deleting it in the database.

Comment: Cool. I got it. Its the on delete url mistake. It should be ` const deleteTodo = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/todos/${id}`, {
        method: "DELETE",
      });`